# Open sharedapplication in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, safari, instagram

I try to open Instagram and Safari from my application, this worked in iOS 5. But now it seems that it's not working anymore. Everything works, no errors, but when I open the app and click on the button it doesn't work...

This is my code to open Instagram:

```
 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"]; if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't open site in Safari only in iOS 6 by openURL. Please help